# Get a following sibling to element but on the same branch?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This flat XML represents tree structure using level field. How can I get elements that are deeper in the tree to the given node but only in the same branch?

So given that company name is A and I need to get company B and C (not E which is in different branch).

```
<Companies>
      <Company>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Level>0</Level>
      </Company>
      <Company>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
      </Company>
      <Company>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
      </Company>
      <Company>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Level>0</Level>
      </Company>
      <Company>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
      </Company>
    </Companies>
```

There can be more than level one. I want it returned too. 
I am using XLST 1.0.

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 here?

Comment: Also, can you more than one level here? (i.e Can you have Level 2 elements)? If so, do you want these returned too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the focus node (current()) is the basis of your calculation.

Define...

```
<xsl:variable name="set1" select="following-sibling::Company[ Level &gt; current()]" />
<xsl:variable name="set2" select="following-sibling::Company[ Level &lt; 
      preceding-sibling::Company[1]/Level][1]/preceding-sibling::Company" />
```

Then the child companies are at the intersection of these two sets, which is...

```
$set1[. = $set2]
```

Comment: Intersection is not supported in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @jlp Correct. Intersection is not **natively** supported in XSLT 1.0. Which is why my solution is as it is. This is how you achieve intersection without native support.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDescendants" match="Company[Level > 0]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Company[Level=0][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="key('kDescendants', generate-id(/*/*[Name='A']))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Companies>
    <Company>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Level>0</Level>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Level>0</Level>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Level>1</Level>
    </Company>
</Companies>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Company>
   <Name>B</Name>
   <Level>1</Level>
</Company>
<Company>
   <Name>C</Name>
   <Level>1</Level>
</Company>
```

**Explanation**:

The key `"kDescendants"` defines the mapping between a top node in the tree and its descendants -- given the `generate-id($someTopNode)`, it produces all descendants in the (logical) tree topped by that `$someTopNode`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this in XSLT1.0 is to define a key, that groups elements by the first-most preceding-sibling with a lower level

```
<xsl:key 
   name="companies" 
   match="Company" 
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Company[Level &lt; current()/Level][1])" />
```

Then, assuming you were positioned on a specific **Company** element for which you want the lower levels, you can just do this

This will initially get the elements on the next level. To get the subsequent levels, you need a template to match the **Company** elements, copy them, and recursively apply the template

```
<xsl:template match="Company">
   <Company>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </Company>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('companies', generate-id())" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="companies" match="Company" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Company[Level &lt; current()/Level][1])" />

   <xsl:template match="/Companies">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Company[Name='A']" mode="parent" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Company" mode="parent">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('companies', generate-id())" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Company">
      <Company>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Company>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('companies', generate-id())" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<Company>
   <Name>B</Name>
   <Level>1</Level>
</Company>
<Company>
   <Name>C</Name>
   <Level>1</Level>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my try - but I believe that there are simpler ways... And sorry: it's XSLT 2.0 only.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Companies">
        <xsl:param name="nodeName" select="'A'" />

        <xsl:variable name="level" select="Company[Name = $nodeName]/Level/text()" as="xs:int"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seq" as="node()*" select="Company[Name = $nodeName]/following-sibling::*" />
        <xsl:variable name="levels" as="xs:int*" select="$seq/Level/text()" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="subsequence($seq, 0, index-of($levels, $level)[1])" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```